# Logistic Regression Error:'x' is NULL so the result will be NULLError in ans[test & ok]

Tags: r

I'm new to R and I'm trying to run a logistic regression model. I've created a cross validation function and a regular model using glm. When I run the regular model, it works fine but when I try using the function it errors.

I've tried defining the Y variable but this errors

`er_log=mycv.logistic(data = train_data, glmfit=payment~., yname="payment", K=3, seed=123)`

**Error in terms.formula(formula, data = data) : argument is not a valid model**

I've also tried using the glm model that originally worked in the function but this gives me a different error

```
glmfit1=glm(payment~., data=train_data, family=binomial)
```

`er_log=mycv.logistic(data = train_data, glmfit=glmfit1, yname="payment", K=3, seed=123)`

**Error in ans[test & ok] <- rep(yes, length.out = length(ans))[test & ok] : replacement has length zero**

This is the function I'm trying to use.

```
mycv.logistic<-

  function (data, glmfit, yname, K, seed=1) { 

   n <- nrow(data)
   set.seed(seed)

   datay=data[,yname]#response variable

   #partition the data into K subsets
   f <- ceiling(n/K)
   s <- sample(rep(1:K, f), n)  

   CV=NULL; O.P=NULL

   for (i in 1:K) { #i=1
     j.out <- seq_len(n)[(s == i)] #test data
     j.in <- seq_len(n)[(s != i)] #training data

     #model with training data
     log.fit=glm(glmfit$call, data=data[j.in,],family = 'binomial')
     #observed test set y
     testy <- datay[j.out]
     #predicted test set y
     log.predy=predict(log.fit, data[j.out,],type='response')

     le=levels(datay)
     class.p = ifelse(log.predy > 0.5,le[2], le[1] )

     #observed - predicted on test data
     error= mean(testy!=class.p)
     ovsp <- cbind(pred=class.p,obs=testy) #pred vs obs vector

     CV <- c(CV,error) 
     O.P <- rbind(O.P,ovsp)
     #error rates 

   }

   #Output
   list(call = glmfit$call, K = K, 
        error = mean(CV), ConfusianMatrix=table(O.P[,1],O.P[,2]), 
        seed = seed)

 }
```

I expect this to output the confusion matrix for the training data so I can ultimately use the model on my testing data.

Answer (score 0):

Just figured it out. Turns out my response variable contained either 0 or 1 and was a numeric value that needed to be converted to a factor.